# magento custom order form

Tags: magento-1.7

Thank you in advance for reading this. Here is the situation. I have been working on a online guitar shop using Magento CE 1.7 for several months. I greatly underestimated the cost of the site and I know that is my fault not the client who by the way is a great guy. There where many issues that took a lot of time including having to move it from a testing server to the real domain, many logo tweaks etc. I am almost done with it and really need to “stop the bleeding” so to speak however there is one feature that he really wants that I am at my whits end with.

Its a custom order form for guitar pickups. He had one on his old site that was don’t in ASP and besides not knowing ASP we are now on a Unix server.

His requirements are “the ability for someone to choose a category (ie: 7-string, Strat Replacement, Tele Replacement, etc) , and then have it be able to only show options that are applicable to what that selection.  I want customers to be able to see descriptions of each pickup somewhere on this page. I also want people to be able to see what the covers/colors look like when they choose that.”

I was able to use the way back machine to at least show you guys what he wants, here is the link http://web-beta.archive.org/web/20120127233223/http://www.axepalace.com/pickup_order.asp

Here is my attempt to create it with a product with lots of options. http://axepalace.com/pickups/bare-knuckle/bkp-order-form/bare-knuckle-pickup-order-form.html

So could anyone please give me some feedback / suggestions. My sanity would really appreciate it!